Build error while trying to use Winmm.h library
I am trying to make program in C, that will play sound from .wav file.
Here's the code that I use:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "winmm.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    PlaySound(TEXT("music002.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
    system("pause");
}

To use this library, I downloaded winmm.h and winmm.dll. I added header file to the project file and also added is to "Header Files" in Solution Explorer. I added path to the winmm.dll file in the Proprieties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories.
I also added **#include <Windows.h>, some online sources suggested it's needed to use library.
Overall, as far as I know, I did everything I could to add library. All functions are listed as good, there's no error underline in all code.
But here's the problem. Visual Studio doesn't compile code. It just pops out "There were build errors." window and doesn't continue.
What do I do wrong?
I'm almost sure, that I'm doing some mistake while adding library, however I cannot figure out what I should do.
Thanks for all replies

You don't link to winmm.dll. you link to winmm.lib. it comes with the platform sdk. Get it here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

From which source did you download winmm.h and winmm.dll? You don't need to download anything.

@Jabberwocky I downloaded winmm.h from github link and Winmm.dll is part of windows libraries, I'm not sure if I had it with my operating system, or was it downloaded with windows-sdk using visual studio installer

@DrakeVimes you don't need winmm.h, including windows.h is enough.

You don't need to include "winmm.h" there is no such thing.

Remove #include "winmm.h"
link to winmm.lib as described below:

Use the Project>Properties command or press Alt+F7 and enter winmm.lib under Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies:

Also make sure you read and understand the documentation.

You also may simply add #pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib"), for example right after #include <Windows.h>:
This should compile and link without hassle:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

int main()
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  PlaySound(TEXT("music002.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
  system("pause");
}


Thank you!
Firstly I tried linking winmm.lib, but still got an error.
But when I add #pragma... it finally worked! Thanks for help one more time
